# Is it possible to dynamically embed a Jupyter Notebook inside another Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am writing a scientific report using notebooks.
I have a document (notebook B), which has my full outline (Intro, methods, results etc).
I want to keep notebook A separate, but I would also like to refer to it directly under one of my headings
Is it possible to dynamically import part of notebook A into notebook B, such that when using nbviewer, it all looks like one huge document, but in reality, it's a bunch of separate notebooks being cobbled together on the fly? I want to be able to update notebook B, and have the changes dynamically also updated in the master notebook A.

I am managing all of the notebooks within a git repository.

I have managed to get hyperlinking between notebooks working well using the basic hyperlinking syntax `[](notebookA.ipynb#SectionIWantToLinkTo)`, but I would like to actually pull in the code cells, not just hyperlink to them.

I want to keep the different workflow documents (i.e. notebooks) separate to make it easier to manage and run the workflow, without having all the extra code from the workflows I don't care about at that time.

The final view will be a hyperlinked document in nbviewer, so a solution that looks ugly within Jupyter/git, but renders well into nbviewer would be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking here Claire.

There isn't a native way to include the contents of one notebook into another, however, here are a variety of alternatives you can consider.

**Merge before commit**

Use the [nbmerge](https://github.com/jbn/nbmerge) tool to merge a few notebooks together into a separate one before committing the result.

**Use a notebook publishing toolkit**
There are projects for using notebooks to publish papers or even entire books such as [bookbook](https://github.com/takluyver/bookbook) and [ipypublish](https://github.com/chrisjsewell/ipypublish). The might be more complicated or restricted than what you want.

**Import code between notebooks**

You could also use [ipynb](https://github.com/ipython/ipynb), or `%run second_notebook.py` to import the code from one notebook into another. You will still have two files, so won't display as a single page, but it can run as one, and links between will still work.

**Restructure another way**

Consider whether it's worth extracting some of the *less interesting* code into a reusable `.py` file or module and importing it. Keep the notebook focused on the main content you want to describe.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
**Merge before commit** - this will do what I need to, but doesn't meet the desire to keep the notebooks actually separate so I can run them independently. This may work just prior to publishing though.
**bookbook or ipypublish** - I did come across these while searching, but they still don't quite do what I need.
**Import code across notebooks** - I want them to run separately, so this wont work for me.
**Restructure** - something to explore a little more, though I like having code and markdown together, hence the desire to use notebooks to publish.